# Bootstrap jumbotron under nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to accomplish this:

http://unity3d.com/community

A full width header image under the navbar: what's the best Bootstrap 3 approach to accomplish this?

I was able to move the jumbotron outside the main container using this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_jumbotron.htm

Now the challenge is to move the navbar back to it's original position at the top of the page (it is currently displayed just after the jumbotron)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding up some custom CSS and HTML:

HTML:

```
<div class="background-image"> </div> /!-- Make sure it is right under the closing head tag! --!/
```

CSS:

```
.background-image {

    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('community.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index: -100;


}
```

After your background div, you can put your jumbotron and customize it. Make sure your image is wide enough ( 1920px is a good width) so that it will look ok on all resolutions. Also, the height must be fixed , otherwise the image is going to take up your whole page.