# Double div "container body-content" tag doesn't align correctly in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why using twice the `<div class="container body-content">` tag, I got an incorrect alignment on the right side of the page? The text goes beyond the right border.

Here is a live version of my page:

**EDIT:** http://www.bootply.com/L22KmZFgrt

Here is the HTML, thanks.

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" >
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cetero veritus mei ne, omnium propriae mel eu.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content" style="position: absolute; top:400px">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cetero veritus mei ne, omnium propriae mel eu. Eos putant signiferumque id, id mea nulla ceteros, an nonumy graeco everti his. Eam corrumpit consequat id. In nec audire accusamus, cu his velit denique aliquando. Ne nulla oratio feugiat ius, usu ut tibique intellegam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cetero veritus mei ne, omnium propriae mel eu. Eos putant signiferumque id, id mea nulla ceteros, an nonumy graeco everti his. Eam corrumpit consequat id. In nec audire accusamus, cu his velit denique aliquando. Ne nulla oratio feugiat ius, usu ut tibique intellegam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cetero veritus mei ne, omnium propriae mel eu. Eos putant signiferumque id, id mea nulla ceteros, an nonumy graeco everti his. Eam corrumpit consequat id. In nec audire accusamus, cu his velit denique aliquando. Ne nulla oratio feugiat ius, usu ut tibique intellegam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this in? I'm not seeing anything odd in Chrome?

Comment: I'm using IE11, the text in the bottom row is not within the navbar width.

Comment: Why did you put style = "position: absolute, top: 400px"?

Comment: @PoseLab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955500/bootstrap-jumbotron-under-nav-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a sort of positioning a  relative to another  and I solved using this great answer: [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)